# If I delete Google account entirely will it delete all the photos saved on my phone?

Tags: photos, google, images

I want to delete my present google account, entirely, but I'm unsure as to whether doing so would delete all the apps on my phone, and all the pictures I've saved, from the Internet and screenshots and being sent them etc.

Answer (score 1):

[This link about deleting google account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046?hl=en) gives you the required information.

As far as I understand, it would not delete the apps and screenshots from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't delete your pics. But, if there are some synced photos of some folder from your Google photos app, those will vanish only from your phone not from cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

No. It won't delete any photos **saved on your phone.** It will delete photos backed up to your Google Photos account though. So make sure you move any photos on your Google account to your phone if you want to keep them.